# Query in q-lang using qPython and Pandas in Python 3.8

Tags: python, pandas, kdb, qpython

I am totally new to q-language, but I need to use it in order to access a kdb server to get the data from.

I am using Python 3.8, under Windows10, with qPython installed.

I have trouble getting the query to the server.

```
from qpython import qconnection
import pandas as pd


tbl = 'q("h\"select from trade where date = 2007.02.28, sym = `XXXX\"")'


q = qconnection.QConnection(host=server, port=server_port, username=user, password=server_password, timeout=server_timeout)

q.open()
df = pd.DataFrame(q.sendSync('tbl'))
q.close()
```

On executing the script it returns an error at line 15:

`qpython.qtype.QException: b'tbl'`

So I have a trouble sending the correct expression to the server. I was able to pass the expression via terminal, using q (with PyQ) under Linux Debian 10, so the query is correct.

(The server details are skipped, as well as the bond name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyQ and qPython are being confused here. `q.sendSync('tbl')` will get the variable tbl from the kdb server. This error: `qpython.qtype.QException: b'tbl'` means tbl doesn't exist on the kdb server. I think what you wanted is the select statement to be sent to the kdb server:

```
from qpython import qconnection
import pandas as pd

q = qconnection.QConnection(host=server, port=server_port, username=user, password=server_password, timeout=server_timeout, pandas=True)

q.open()
df = q.sendSync('select from trade where date = 2007.02.28, sym = `XXXX')
q.close()
```

It might be worth while for you to spend sometime with q itself and get up to speed with some basics here:

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/1_Q_Shock_and_Awe/

Comment: Thank you so much about the fix with the query.

And even more I thank you about the link. (I actually had seen it in the past, but I thought I would not need to learn Q language in details, as I need just the query.)

I have printed df. However I see all the numbers are quite strange. The date for example is listed as '2615'... and all the rest: time, etc.

Comment: `import datetime from datetime # if your kdb table has dates and times` from my previous answer

Comment: ```from qpython import qconnection
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime```

Still the date and time is not good looking.

Comment: add `, pandas = True` to `qconnection.QConnection`. Seems to work for me. May not even need `pd.DataFrame`